# Cannot deploy properly a WAR in tomcat 8.5/ubuntu 18.04 with tomcat manager

Tags: tomcat8, ubuntu-18.04

In ubuntu since 18.04, deploying an application using tomcat manager html (with "standard" tomcat8 and tomca8-admin packages installed) using "Deploy directory or WAR file located on server" does not seem to work anymore.

Only the war is deployed in the given context, but without its configuration set in "XML Configuration file URL:", the context file  is not copied anymore in /var/lib/tomcat8/conf/Catalina/localhost

It is working with ubuntu 16.04. It is not working with 18.04 and 18.10.

Do I missed some steps in tomcat configuration to have manager working in ubuntu 18.04 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tomcat8/+bug/1820288) with a simple project attached to reproduce the issue: